# How do I implement a structure with a callback with a compound data type as argument?

Tags: rust

I succeeded with primitive data types as arguments, but I have a difficult time doing it for compound data types in arguments.

```rust
fn main() {
    let renderer = Render::new("name1".to_string());
}

pub struct UpdateEvent {
    pub dt: f64,
}

pub struct Render<OnUpdate>
where
    OnUpdate: Fn(&mut UpdateEvent),
{
    pub name: String,
    pub f_on_update: OnUpdate,
}

impl<OnUpdate> Render<OnUpdate>
where
    OnUpdate: Fn(&mut UpdateEvent),
{
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Render<OnUpdate> {
        let f_on_update = |e: &mut UpdateEvent| {};
        Render { name, f_on_update }
    }
}
```

It throws 2 errors:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations needed: cannot satisfy `for<'r> <_ as FnOnce<(&'r mut UpdateEvent,)>>::Output == ()`
  --> src/main.rs:2:20
   |
2  |     let renderer = Render::new("name1".to_string());
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot satisfy `for<'r> <_ as FnOnce<(&'r mut UpdateEvent,)>>::Output == ()`
...
21 |     pub fn new(name: String) -> Render<OnUpdate> {
   |     -------------------------------------------- required by `Render::<OnUpdate>::new`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:24
   |
17 | impl<OnUpdate> Render<OnUpdate>
   |      -------- this type parameter
...
22 |         let f_on_update = |e: &mut UpdateEvent| {};
   |                           ------------------------ the found closure
23 |         Render { name, f_on_update }
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `OnUpdate`, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `OnUpdate`
                     found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:22:27: 22:51]`
   = help: every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `OnUpdate`
```

Where do I look?

Comment: Is there a reason you're parameterizing on the type of `OnUpdate`? You might consider using trait objects and just letting `f_on_update` have type `Box<dyn Fn(...)>`. Remember that closures always have their own distinct singleton type, so your `Render::new` is technically returning a *different* type of value every time it's called, not one of your choosing.

Comment: Thank you Silvio, non-generic solution with pointers ```Box< dyn Fn( &mut UpdateEvent ) >``` works. But what about generic solution? Does such exist?

Comment: You may be able to do something exciting with `impl` return types. It's an interesting question, and I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get your code working, in my opinion, is to pass the value used for `f_on_update` via the `new` function, rather than define it within the `new` function:

```
fn main() {
    let renderer = Render::new("name1".to_string(), |_| {});
    let mut ue = UpdateEvent { dt: 5. };
    (renderer.f_on_update)(&mut ue);
}

pub struct UpdateEvent {
    pub dt: f64,
}

pub struct Render<OnUpdate>
where
    OnUpdate: Fn(&mut UpdateEvent),
{
    pub name: String,
    pub f_on_update: OnUpdate,
}

impl<OnUpdate> Render<OnUpdate>
where
    OnUpdate: Fn(&mut UpdateEvent),
{
    pub fn new(name: String, f: OnUpdate) -> Render<OnUpdate> {
        Render {
            name,
            f_on_update: f,
        }
    }
}
```

I think you're running into two errors in the given code:

1. In the main function, there is not enough information given for the compiler to infer what the value of the type parameter `OnUpdate` is.  This causes the first error, which is asking you to add type annotation. I believe, this also leads to the second error.
2. In `Render::new`, the compiler doesn't know what the value of the type parameter `OnUpdate` is, so it can't know that the closure you're defining with `|e: &mut UpdateEvent| {}` is the correct type.

Comment: Thank you, egerhard. Is that possible to add field ```renderer : &'a Render,``` into structure ```UpdateEvent```?

Comment: Interesting. Why bulky callback does not work in ```Renderer::new```, but works in ```main```?

Comment: @Kos with the current design of `Render` I don't believe it would be possible: because `UpdateEvent` would also have to have a type parameter and the current design of `Render` would lead to a recursive type parameter.

Comment: The callback doesn't work when it's defined in `Render::new` because Rust doesn't use the code within `new` to resolve the type parameter `OnUpdate`; instead, it uses the context around the value of `Render` when it's created and used to resolve `OnUpdate` to a type.